# What is the correct way to use MainWindow functions in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am creating a UserControl and calling it within my MainWindow

I use Visibility as Hidden to not show the UserControl window, so I create a button on MainWindow and click to change Visibility to Visible

Inside the UserControl code I create another button and call MainWindow Visibility and set it to Hidden again

Is this a correct way of working?

My code:

**UserControl.xaml**

```
<Grid Background="White">
        <TextBlock Height="125" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="My UserControl" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="48" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="345"/>
        <Button Content="HidenUserControl" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="75" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="255" Click="HidenUserControl"/>

</Grid>
```

**UserControl.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void HidenUserControl(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow main = (MainWindow)Window.GetWindow(this);

            main.EnableUserControl.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
        <Border Name="EnableUserControl" Background="#66000000" Visibility="Hidden">
            <local:MyUserControl Margin="105,105,72,155" />
        </Border>
        
        <Button Content="ShowUserControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="680,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="ShowUseControl"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ShowUseControl(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EnableUserControl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: A UserControl never accesses a Window or any other element outside its own element tree. In order to interact with the "outside world", it exposes bindable properties, i.e. dependency properties.

Comment: @Clemens What should I do ? Create a new window?

Comment: Of course not. Do not interact with any Window at all. If you would explain what you are actually trying to achieve, we might tell you how to do that.

Comment: I wanted to create a userconf for the user to define their settings

Comment: I mean the show and hide functionality, how should that work? Why can't you have a single ToggleButton that shows and hides the UserControl? Why does the UserControl need to "hide itself"?

Comment: I don't have a single button because I create a Border as if it were an overlay on the main box, so the need for 2 buttons, one to open and one to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move `Border` around your control inside `UserControl` and then mame `EnableUserControl` should be assigned for the control itself.
Then, you can simply write:

```cs
private void HidenUserControl(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

No need to reference MainWindow.
If moving `Border` inside is not by some reasons convinient, you should still move name from `Border` to `UserControl` and bind `Visibility` of `Border` to `Visibility` of control.

```
Visibility={Binding Visibility, ElementName=EnableUserControl}
```

Comment: I even tried to use it that way, but then the MainWindow button after the first time doesn't open the usercontrol window anymore

Comment: I got it - you actually show/hide not the control, but a border around it

Comment: Changed my answer.